# ARM Template assign multiple cert thumbprint to WEBSITES_LOAD_CERTIFICATES

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Am working on ARM template to deploy the application to Azure App service and want to load the two certificate's thumbprint in WEBSITES_LOAD_CERTIFICATES in App Settings of App service.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
  "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/',variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/certificates/',variables('certificateName'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms',variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES",
          "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))).Thumbprint]"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I have tried as below but that giving error. I do not find any help to load two certificates thumbprint.

```
"properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms',variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES",
          "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))).Thumbprint],[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName1'))).Thumbprint]"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
```

please help to load two certificate thumbprint to WEBSITES_LOAD_CERTIFICATES using ARM template
Tried as below but loading only second cert thumbprint.

```
"appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))).Thumbprint]",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName1'))).Thumbprint]"
            },
```

Comment: Just concat() them with a ';' as seperator

Comment: Specifying `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES = *` is also an alternative solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use the [concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-array#concat) function to combines multiple string values.
Please have a try to use the following code.

```
"value":"[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName'))).Thumbprint,',',reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/certificates', variables('certificateName1'))).Thumbprint)]"
```